# Deployed prometheus with Django and Kubernetes, how to make it scrape the Django app?

Tags: django, kubernetes, prometheus

I have a Django project deployed in Kubernetes and I am trying to deploy Prometheus as a monitoring tool. I have successfully done all the steps needed to include `django_prometheus` in the project and locally I can go go `localhost:9090` and play around with querying the metrics.

I have also deployed Prometheus to my Kubernetes cluster and upon running a `kubectl port-forward ...` on the Prometheus pod I can see some metrics of my Kubernetes resources.

Where I am a bit confused is how to make the deployed Django app metrics available on the Prometheus dashboard just like the others.
I deployed my app in `default` namespace and  prometheus in a `monitoring` dedicated namespace. I am wondering what am I missing here. Do I need to expose the ports on the service and deployment from 8000 to 8005 according to the number of workers or something like that?

My Django app runs with gunicorn using `supervisord` like so:

```
[program:gunicorn]
command=gunicorn --reload --timeout 200000 --workers=5 --limit-request-line 0 --limit-request-fields 32768 --limit-request-field_size 0 --chdir /code/ my_app.wsgi
```

- `my_app` service:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my_app
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: my-app
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

- Trimmed version of the `deployment.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
  name: my-app-deployment
  namespace: default
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: ...
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: my-app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

- `prometheus configmap`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  prometheus.rules: |-
    ... some rules
  prometheus.yml: |-
    global:
      scrape_interval: 5s
      evaluation_interval: 5s
    rule_files:
      - /etc/prometheus/prometheus.rules
    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: prometheus
        static_configs:
        - targets:
          - localhost:9090

      - job_name: my-app
        metrics_path: /metrics
        static_configs:
          - targets:
            - localhost:8000

      - job_name: 'node-exporter'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
          - role: endpoints
        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoints_name]
          regex: 'node-exporter'
          action: keep

kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    name: prometheus-config
  name: prometheus-config
  namespace: monitoring
```

Comment: Did any of provided solutions help you?

Comment: I haven't had the change to properly apply both suggestions. I'll post an update when I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to expose the application outside the cluster.

Leveraging the Kubernetes service discovery, add the job to scrape Services, Pods, or both:

```
- job_name: 'kubernetes-service-endpoints'
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
    action: keep
    regex: true
  - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
    action: replace
    regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
    replacement: $1:$2
    target_label: __address__
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
    action: replace
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    regex: (.+)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    action: replace
    target_label: namespace
    regex: (.+)
  - regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
    action: labelmap
  - regex: 'app_kubernetes_io_(.+)'
    action: labeldrop
  - regex: 'helm_sh_(.+)'
    action: labeldrop
```

```
- job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: pod
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
    action: keep
    regex: true
  - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
    action: replace
    regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
    replacement: $1:$2
    target_label: __address__
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
    action: replace
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    regex: (.+)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    action: replace
    target_label: namespace
    regex: (.+)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name]
    action: replace
    target_label: host
    regex: (.+)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    action: replace
    target_label: pod
    regex: (.+)
  - regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
    action: labelmap
  - regex: 'app_kubernetes_io_(.+)'
    action: labeldrop
  - regex: 'helm_sh_(.+)'
    action: labeldrop
```

Then, annotate the Service with:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    prometheus.io/port: "80"
    prometheus.io/path: "/metrics"
```

and the Deployment with:

```
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
     annotations:
      prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
      prometheus.io/port: "80"
      prometheus.io/path: "/metrics"
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. And sorry for the late response. I still can't get it to scrape. Could it be because the path in my Django app in "/metrics" goes through a middleware requiring authentication for it? Even though it's inside the cluster

Comment: In Django, I've added the app and the url config, by default there isn't authentication to access the metrics endpoint

Comment: In our project every url path goes through a middleware that requires login authentication. That's a security measure by default

Comment: Ok, so you have to add the authN to scrape config. See here (https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config) for more details

Comment: Yes, but at the moment the "authentication" required is a login at "/admin/login" which is the response redirected when accessing `/metrics` unauthenticated. How can I have /metrics with a different authentication?

Comment: I removed the auth for now in a development version and I added all the annotations to the service and deployment as you suggested. I also added the two jobs to the prometheus.conf but still no success. I can `curl` the `/metrics` endpoint and get the metrics but prometheus is hitting `http://my-app.default.svc.cluster.local/metrics` (with or without port) and getting a `server returned HTTP status 400 Bad Request`

Comment: Both methods work now. But for annotation and service discovery, I would need to add the IP  from the service `xx.xx.xx.xx/metrics` to the ALLOWED HOSTS configuration in Django which I can't know beforehand. Or add the external address of the service in the cluster `my_app.default.svc.cluster.local`. Is there a workaround here?

Comment: In Django, I've added the cluster private network as "trusted" with `ALLOWED_CIDR_NETS = [ 'a.b.c.d/16']`

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to expose services, if the promehteus is installed on the same cluster as your app. You can communicate with apps between namespaces by using Kubernetes DNS resolution, going by the rule:

```
SERVICENAME.NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local
```

so one way is to change your prometheus job target to something like this

```yaml
  - job_name: speedtest-ookla
    metrics_path: /metrics
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - 'my_app.default.svc.cluster.local:9000'
```

And this is the "manual" way. A better approach will be to use prometheus `kubernetes_sd_config`. It will autodiscover your services and try to scrape them.

Reference: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#kubernetes_sd_config

Comment: I tried this solution but I still get an error in prometheus dashboard `Get "http://my_app.default.svc.cluster.local:8000/metrics": context deadline exceeded`. It works for prometheus though.

Comment: @everspader change the port to 80, not 8000. Your `Deployment` is listening on 80 port, the same as the `Service`. Also look on the @Marco answer. It will automaticly scrape your deployments and services.